# How to correctly say "This function begins at infinity"?

Tags: functions

Consider a function,

$$
f\left(x\right)=\frac{x^{2}}{4-x^{2}},-2<x\le1.
$$

If one is simply looking at its graph, which looks like a U with the left arm coming down from infinity and the right arm stopping at $x=1$, how do I correctly say that this graph does not have a maximum value? I am at a loss on how to articulate this in a mathematically correct way.

Comment: Perhaps "Unbounded"? Maybe "not bounded above"...

Comment: What's wrong wit simply saying that $f$ doesn't have a maximum? A stronger (and true) assertion would be that $f$ is not bounded above.

Comment: As for the title (which doesn't match with your "does not have a maximum"): The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $-2$ from the right is $+\infty.$

Comment: It begins at $(-2^{+},\infty)$...?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos and morrowmh - Thank you, that is what I was looking for.